# Rapidly selecting a choice in the auto-completion context menu in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

Is there any quick way select a choice in the auto-completion context menu in Eclipse?

For example, in the following screenshot, I would like to directly select and enter the fourth option, i.e. `format_data`. How can I do that with the keyboard without having to hit ↓ three times or type `rmat_d`? E.g., typing `4` instead (which doesn't work).

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.